# How to create a list with variable number of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I am trying to create a list "pool" like this:

```
> n=10
> pool=list(0:n,0:n,0:n)
> pool
[[1]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Instead of typing the 0:n three times, I need to use a line of code to represent it because the number of repeats changes over time. I tried:

```
> K=3
> pool=NULL
> for (i in 1:K){
+   pool=list(pool,0:n)
+ }
> pool
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


[[1]][[2]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10


[[2]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

but they are different. How can I make it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rep`:

```r
k <- 3

rep(list(0:n), k)
```

Or you can use `purrr::map`:

```r
purrr::map(1:k, ~0:n)
```

Output

```r
[[1]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[2]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

[[3]]
 [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replicate` :

```
n = 10
K = 3

pool <- replicate(K, 0:n, simplify = FALSE)
pool

#[[1]]
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#[[2]]
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

#[[3]]
# [1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

`replicate` is similar to `purrr::rerun`

```
pool <- purrr::rerun(K, 0:n)
```